# Does shortening the notation $n=1,2,3,...$ as $n\in\mathbb{N}$ lead to disambiguity?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, terminology

I'm confused by this seemingly trivial question.

The notation $$n=1,2,3,...$$ usually means 'where $n$ is any natural number', or 'For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$'.

What if I replace $n=1,2,3,...$ by $n\in\mathbb{N}$, will it lead to disambiguation?

For example, are notations (a) and (b) below are equivalent?
$$
\text{Let } F  \text{ be a functional such that } F[x^n]=0, \qquad n=1,2,3,...,\tag{a}
$$
$$
\text{Let } F  \text{ be a functional such that }  F[x^n]=0, \qquad n\in\mathbb{N}.\tag{b}
$$

I think (b) might be understood also 'for just one fixed natural number $n$'. So the notations are not equivalent in general?

Comment: In both versions you should write “for all $n$ ...” to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @MartinR ok thanks.

Comment: @MartinR +1. It is not the meaning of  $n\in\mathbb N$ that is imprecise, it is the fact that the *quantifier* is missing. ("For all $n$...", or, perhaps (in a different context), "There exists $n$..."/"For at least one $n$...")

Comment: @StinkingBishop I thought the notation $n=1,2,3,...$ used in older books means 'for all $n$' automatically, no?

Comment: @PeppaPig As a *reader*, I would tend to agree with what you say. As a *writer*, I would prefer to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Also, sometimes $\mathbb N$ has $0$, sometimes not.

Comment: Probably not the ambiguity you were concerned about but, oddly, there isn't universal agreement as to what $\mathbb N$ means.  Some writers include $0$, others don't.  That's a strong reason for spelling out the intended set.

Comment: You can also write “for all positive integers” or “for all non-negative integers” to avoid any ambiguity.

Comment: If you want the positive integers, use an unambiguous notation like $\Bbb Z^+$; for many of us $\Bbb N$ is synonymous with $\omega$ and includes $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should make clear that you're not considering $0$ as a natural number. Then, to avoid thinking you refer to a single $n$, you may better write:
$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$
instead of just $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Given this, the meaning of both expressions is the same.